# How create Dynamic Resource for Entry and Label text values in Xamarin.Forms VS2015

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, label, xamarin.forms.entry

How to save the value entered through an Entry to then be shown on a label? 
All the examples I find only show cosmetic factors in the application.

Comment: Read about data binding https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101/

Answer (score 4):

You can bind both the `Entry` and your `Label` to the same Viewmodel property.

XAML :

```
<Entry Text={Binding MyText} />    
<Label Text={Binding MyText} />
```

Viewmodel :

```
private string _myText;    
public string MyText 
{
  get 
  {
     return _myText;
  }
  set
  {
    _myText = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

You can find more samples at [Interactive_MVVM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/#Interactive_MVVM)

Or you can do a View to View Binding :

```
<Entry x:Name="Entry1" Text="{Binding Country}"/>
<Label BindingContext="{x:Reference Entry1}" Text="{Binding BindingContext.Country}"/>
```

You can find more samples at [View-to-View Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#View-to-View_Bindings)

Comment: @EloiSartori - if it helped you please accept the answer, so that it would help future users who stumble upon the same problem.